# Backbone.js view events are not firing

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have followed numerous screen casts as well as trawled the backbone docs extensively and I cannot figure out why my view events are not being fired. My (short) code for testing is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var App = (function($){
        
        var NavigationItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#navigation',
            initialize: function(params){
                this.label = params.label;
                this.appendTo = params.appendTo;
            },
            events: {
                "click #add" : "test"
            },
            test: function(){
                $(this.el).html("<li>Testing...</li>");
            },
            render: function(){
                $(this.el).html("<li><a href=\"#\">"+this.label+"</a></li>");
            }
        })
        
        var self = {};
        self.init = function(){
            new NavigationItemView({ label: 'Test Nav Label' });
        }
        
        return self;
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
         App(jQuery).init();
    })
    
</script>
```

**If I change the init method code from this:**

```
new NavigationItemView({ label: 'Test Nav Label' })
```

**To this:**

```
new NavigationItemView({ label: 'Test Nav Label' }).render()
```

The render method is called perfectly, indicating there is no issues with the set up of the view. I can replace `render()` with `test()` and likewise it works.

However, the event of clicking on the link with ID #add does not fire the test even, and surely it should? To clarify, I do have a link with id 'add' in the DOM, I have checked and checked again.

If I add event hooks using jQuery and fire off certain methods of the view manually, that works. It's backbones own event hooks that are not working for me.

I have looked at the related posts, and most of the suggestions were use the **el** property, which I have. `#navigation` is an empty `<ul>` in my case. I have changed it to a div but with no change in behaviour.

All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your #add element a child of your view element (#navigation)?
Events are fired only on children elements of you view "el". For instance, this will not work:

```
<div id="navigation">
    ...
</div>

<div id="add">
    ...
</div>
```

While this will:

```
<div id="navigation">
    ...
    <div id="add">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
 </div>
```

Comment: I am confused, on the screen casts I watched, both said that that it will only work as you describe if the el is NOT present, but if el IS present then the clickable element does not have to be a child? In other words, when assigning the container element to el, the clickable element may be anywhere in the DOM, hmmmm :/

Comment: Nope, even if the el is present, the clickable element has to be a child. I had the same problem a few days ago, only way I could fix it was changing the el or the clickable element =/

Comment: I moved the element into the <ul> - although tehcnically incorrect from a DOM layout perspective, having an <a> immediately under the <ul> - but it did work as you suggested. So this begs the question, is there a way to bind (or better yet live) the events to elements that are outside the parent element, or that have not yet been created? I can fallback to using jQuery but I really thought the entire idea was to have a modular approach, and that's exactly what I'm after hence using backbone here.

Comment: Another way around would be to directly bind the event in your initialize like this:

$("#element").bind("click", function() {
        new App.Views.YourView().function();
      });

You'll have to create a new view though.

Comment: Ya, that was how I initially did it, but my idea was to have all my views in a single external file. Okay, well thank you for clearing this up. I have one more thing I am going to try that MIGHT work, and will post it if it does. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, well the method I followed in the end was to wrap my entire set of DOM elements I wanted to use for events etc in a div with an ID, then I targeted the parent div as the el property and drilled down the DOM using jQuery. So el:"#wrapper" was used and then I simply drilled down deeper in the methods, eg `render: function(){ $(this.el).find('ul#someUl').append('<li>...</li>'); }`

Comment: And I am certain with some thought we can even wrap that container element inside a paramter name that can be optionally passed to the view at runtime, otherwise default to #wrapper

Comment: it took me forever to figure out why this wasn't working. You can't do a click on the el itself, either. It must be a child, seemingly. Thanks Ronan.